# testing programs that modify and rely on enviroment

Tags: testing, rust, automated-tests

I am writing a rust CLI tool for managing software configurations. Naturally this program relies heavily on the environment in which it runs, looking at certain files their locations and contents as well as environment variables, the users on the system, etc. With some basic functionality implemented I want to start thinking about more advanced tests than the basic unit tests i have implemented. I want to test my application using its CLI in different environments. I have researched end to end testing (i think this is what i want) but everything seems to be oriented toward web development. I have wondered if docker would be suited for this sort of thing, does it have mechanisms that would allow me to prototype an environment to test my application in? Overall i am wondering what the best way to approach this kind of problem is or even if it is a problem in the first place and i should take another approach when testing software like this.

Comment: Running some scripts in docker is definitely a good idea because this would ensure that your program modify environment inside isolated container so it would not broke a machine which runs tests.